# Ruby on Rails: Post.find(8) vs Post.where(:id => 8) statements, can't get comments for Post.where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, find

This brings the comments with post_id=8

```
@onepost = Post.find(8)
@allpostsWithAssoc = @onepost.comments
```

But this doesn't bring the comments with post_id=8, but why ?

```
@onepost = Post.where(:id => 8)
@allpostsWithAssoc = @onepost.comments
```

I get

```
undefined method `comments' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x9ecfce4>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of `@onepost = Post.where(:id => 8)` is a collection (or Array) of all Post records which matched the condition, not the the record itself. try this:

```
@onepost = Post.where(:id => 8).first
@allpostsWithAssoc = @onepost.comments
```

Comment: Which is better to use ? `@onepost = Post.where(:id => 8).first` or `@onepost = Post.find(8)`, which query is faster or are both same ?

Comment: What do you mean by record? How can i know the object type whether it's a collection/array or record? `@onepost = Post.where(:id => 8) logger.debug(@onepost)` and `@onepost = Post.find(8) logger.debug(@onepost)` give same result though.

Comment: the "record" is mean the specific Post which id is "8". if you are using the method "where" with conditions, you will always get the collection/array. using inspect to check: logger.debug(@onepost.inspect) and you will see the post in an array of "[]"

Comment: If i do `<%= debug(@onepost) %>` i get same result for both statements.

Comment: what about if you do <%= debug(@onepost.inspect) %> ?
or using rails console:\n
$ rails console \n
Post.find(8) \n
Post.where(:id => 8)

Comment: It's all hash. Both have same result with @onepost.inspect

Answer (score 2):

`.where` returns a relation. Even if you know that only one object matches the criteria, it is still a collection.

From [the docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions)

> The where method allows you to specify conditions to limit the records
>   returned, representing the WHERE-part of the SQL statement. Conditions
>   can either be specified as a string, array, or hash.

Try

```
@onepost = Post.where(:id => 8).first
@allpostsWithAssoc = @onepost.comments
```

to pick the first of (potentially numerous) matched records.

Comment: Which is better to use ? `@onepost = Post.where(:id => 8).first` or `@onepost = Post.find(8)`, which query is faster or are both same ?

Comment: `Post.find` will raise an exception if record is not found. Because of this I usually use the `where.first` form, which (if record is missing) will return `nil`. 
Which one is faster - is measurable by benchmarks. I am not ready to answer this. :-) 
(though, I'd guess that they both compile to the same query (and perform equally fast))

Comment: > "I'd guess that they both compile to the same query" \
You can easily check that in ActiveRecord debug log.